# Svelte store assignment calls default writable().set and then custom .set?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-store

[Relevant REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/019fe21a45554404948d91d8de908950?version=3.24.0)

I have a simple writable store with a custom `set` method:

```
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
function createState() {
    const {subscribe, set, update} = writable({a: 0, b: 0});
    return {
        subscribe,
        set: (newState) => {
            console.log(newState);
            // set(newState); // I would expect `state` to be unchanged without this
        }
    };
};

export const state = createState();
```

When I call `state.set(<some new value>)`, the new value is logged to the console and the value of `state` does not actually change.  This is what I expect.
However, if I assign `$state = <some new value>`, the value of `state` changes, and *then* `set` logs it to the console.  Why (and how) does this happen, and is there a way around it without reimplementing `writable`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is expected behaviour! Forget about stores for a moment, and — since `state.set` is a noop in your example — remove that line:

```html
<script>
    // import { state } from "./stores.js";

    let pojo = { a: 0, b: 0 };
    pojo.a = 1;
    pojo = {d: 0};

    //state.set({c: 0}); // no effect, as expected
</script>

<h1>state: {JSON.stringify(pojo)}</h1>
```

The outcome...

> `state: {"d":0}`

...is exactly what you'd expect.

When we replace `pojo` with `$state`, we're still assigning to (or mutating) a local variable, with the same reactivity characteristics. The only difference is that we're *also* calling `state.set`. Ordinarily that would cause a change in the store value that would be reflected to its subscribers, but since your custom store doesn't do that, we're left with the value following the last time `$state` was touched by an assignment operator.

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation!  I've accepted this answer because it explains _why_ this is the behavior.  If anyone comes across this question and wants to know more about _what_ is happening, Thomas and Andreas provided some excellent insight there as well.  

(Incidentally, I originally asked this question because I wanted updating my store to have side effects instead of/before assignment.  It seems like that would not be Svelteish, and so I've restructured my app so that logic is moved elsewhere.)

Comment: The explanation turns out to be a lot simpler than I expected, and yet very logical. Thanks Rich!

Answer (score 4):

In the JS output of your REPL, you can see the following:

```js
function instance($$self, $$props, $$invalidate) {
    let $state;
    component_subscribe($$self, state, $$value => $$invalidate(0, $state = $$value));
    set_store_value(state, $state.a = 1, $state); // changes the value of state?!
    set_store_value(state, $state = { d: 0 }); // ''
    state.set({ c: 0 }); // no effect, as expected
    return [$state];
}
```

Using the shorthand reactive assignment `$<store>` compiles into `set_store_value()` calls, which is a svelte internal method defined [thusly](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/blob/master/src/runtime/internal/utils.ts):

```js
export function set_store_value(store, ret, value = ret) {
    store.set(value);
    return ret;
}
```

So the assigned value is, in effect, passed on to your store's `set` function, as you would expect.

**However**, you can see in the JS output above that the value ultimately returned is a *local* variable called `$state` (the `$` sign there is *not* a reactive modifier, just part of the name). During those `set_store_value()` calls, you can see that this local variable is assigned the same value that is passed on to your store's `set` method (in fact, the local variable is assigned that value, and then is itself passed on to the `set_store_value()` method):

```js
set_store_value(state, $state.a = 1, $state); // changes the value of state?!
set_store_value(state, $state = { d: 0 }); // ''
```

I expect this behavior to be some sort of optimistic look-ahead/resolution.

Perhaps it is implied in the [Svelte store contract](https://svelte.dev/docs#Store_contract) that a value passed to a store's `set` method *must* in fact modify the store accordingly, in which case the optimistic resolution approach would always yield coherent results?

Hopefully Rich Harris (or another Svelte contributor) will see your question and provide a more definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Thomas Hennes great analysis:

```
set_store_value(state, $state.a = 1, $state);
```

This internal call updates the internal store model (`$state.a = 1`) without using the `set` or `update` method. To me, this is a bit unexpected and probably a svelte bug. At least, it's something that we need to keep in mind when we design sophisticated custom stores and want to use the store shorthands.